# Kendo Treeview - node multiselect

Tags: angular, kendo-treeview

Looking for the following solution:
I am using Kendo Treeview component in Angular 15 environment. I have a requirement to implement a node multiselect when a user keeps CRTL down - a standard way of selecting multiple rows. The component itself has a multiselect functionality built in. However, it does not require CTRL being pressed to work.
Has anyone figured out a way of adding CTRL to make it work?

Thanks